# How to validate a url address and make sure it contains at least part of a url in javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, xhtml

For this example lets say I want to validate a google plus profile URL in JavaScript.

A typical google plus profile URL looks like:

```
https://plus.google.com/115025207826515678661
```

I basically want to make sure at least the beginning of what was typed in the text input form was:

```
http OR https ://plus.google.com/
```

How could this be done in JavaScript? Every example I find is just a simple validate if its a URL or not.  Not if it contains part of a specific URL.

Comment: JavaScript!=Java.  Removed Java tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *could* use a regex such as `/^https?:\/\/plus\.google\.com/`, but, I'd rather use the DOM.

This should do it...

```
var str = 'https://plus.google.com/115025207826515678661',
    a = document.createElement('a');

a.href = str;

var valid = ((a.protocol == 'http:' || a.protocol == 'https:')
              && a.hostname == 'plus.google.com'
            );
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Q8CaQ/).

Answer (score 0):

Do string comparision with `indexOf("...") != -1`